# how to configure php to work with mysql with out recompilation

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have installed LAMP on **ubuntu** but my php is not compiled to work with mysql.
is it possible to configure php as it is with out uninstalling and recompiling?

Comment: How did you know that? Are you sure there is no mysql support? (If there is no, how did you do it?)))

Comment: I am sure you are doing sth wrong. Write down how you installed the LAMP step by step and which versions

Comment: yeah i was sure, now i reinstalled it

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive it's not compiled to work? Try installing the mysql php module manually.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, normally MySQL is supported by default. Follow this steps to recompile your PHP: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: Btw, it's going to be deprecated soon: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

> PHP 5.0.x, 5.1.x, 5.2.x
>
> MySQL is no longer enabled by default, so the php_mysql.dll DLL must
>   be enabled inside of php.ini. Also, PHP needs access to the MySQL
>   client library. A file named libmysql.dll is included in the Windows
>   PHP distribution and in order for PHP to talk to MySQL this file needs
>   to be available to the Windows systems PATH. See the FAQ titled "How
>   do I add my PHP directory to the PATH on Windows" for information on
>   how to do this. Although copying libmysql.dll to the Windows system
>   directory also works (because the system directory is by default in
>   the system's PATH), it's not recommended.
>
> PHP 5.3.0+
>
> The MySQL Native Driver is enabled by default. Include php_mysql.dll,
>   but libmysql.dll is no longer required or used.